# Uh-oh. It looks like the hat van broke down. The winterbash 2014 page displays an error

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

Navigating to the following url causes a server error. I know it doesn't start until the 15th but though it'd still be useful to report.

http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/

[image]

Comment: It is fixed again!

Comment: So it is! Looks like they applied some unicorn grease to the site.

Comment: Na na na na na na na na na na na na na na na na Hat Van!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a build issue that caused the downtime.

We have resolved the direct issue and the site is back up.

Comment: How many precious seconds were lost for all eternity during this downtime?

Comment: 3. Possibly 4. May have been 2014. Not sure.

Comment: Gather the snowflakes and count back @ShadowWizard.

Comment: @Bart starting doing it now. Will be back in 6-8 weeks with the results! :D

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: We don't think of this as "downtime". We prefer the term "unexpected productivity spike". You're welcome. ;-)